# Adding Relationships between views in Devart entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, odata, devart

I want to have a relation between views in EF. I am following this post to modify it in the xml file.
http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/.

I am getting error,

```
Custom tool error: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'VIEW' in relationship 'FK_'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be 1.
```

I am not really sure if I am going the right path.

The main goal of doing this is to use this entity over oData, and have links to the Ids in the view. I am not using the tables directly, because the table has Ids and I want the names to be sent back to the client. The relationship should give the child details.

If there is any other way to achieve this, please help!!

Thanks in Advance